# Bootstrap 4 nav nav-tabs border bottom full width of the screen

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a question about Bootstrap `nav nav-tabs`, how can I achieve same behavior as it is shown on a picture (bottom border is full width of the screen) and tabs are in the center of the page?

[image]

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_navs.asp Toggleable / Dynamic Tabs. It will always full width.

Answer (score 0):

```
.bottom {
    bottom: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Add the above class in the CSS

```css
.bottom {
  bottom: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<body>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs justify-content-center bottom">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Algo</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">DS</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Languages</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

</body>
```